# Can you build in 2.93, and render in 2.92?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, export, blend-files, compatibility

because Blender has decided to release 2.93 without Windows 7 support, I'm forced to use a PC with poor graphics. I still have 2.92 on a different PC with excellent graphics, which I'd like to use for just the rendering. Unfortunately this other PC cannot run Windows 10.
My question is, can I export my work from 2.93 to 2.92 for the cycles rendering? I'm unclear if the .blend file can do this.

Comment: if you can't open the 2.93 file with 2.92 you can still append all your objects in a 2.92 file

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: File > Append, then open the Object folder and append all your objects, it should work

Comment: So you mean, go to File -> Append in 2.92 ? then open the folder that contains the 2.93 objects ?

Comment: File -> Append in 2.92, double click on the file, you'll see a series of folders (Actions, Armatures, etc), open Objects, select them all and Append

Comment: Thank you moonboots, I'll give it a try

Comment: OK, it worked... in File->Append in 2.92, I opened my 2.93 Blender file, then opened each "append" folder individually and pressed A to select all its contents, and pressed Append. I didn't realize it, but you need to do this for each folder, one at a time, and click Append for each. Turns out I didn't need some of these append folders, only Collection, Image, Light, Material, Mesh, Object, Scene, Texture, and World... Anyway, I can now do a cycles render and bake in 2.92. Thanks for your help. I can now use my crappy 2.93 PC to build, and the better 2.92 computer to render and bake. THANK YOU

Comment: actually if you append collections and world you should have everything, no?